# SQL Statement Help Needed:Query within a Query

Tags: sql

I am working on a query where I need to compile a list of of members who have a particular group of products associated with their, from a particular site and then for each member in that list retrieve all of the products on their account.

The first piece of the query is this:

```
SELECT        
    MEMBERS.memid
FROM            
    SITES 
INNER JOIN
    MEMBERS ON SITES.siteid = MEMBERS.siteid 
INNER JOIN
    SS ON MEMBERS.memid = SS.memid 
INNER JOIN
    PRODUCTCATS 
INNER JOIN
    PRODUCTS ON PRODUCTCATS.productcatid = PRODUCTS.productcatid 
    ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid 
INNER JOIN
    EMPLOYEES ON SS.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
WHERE        
    (PRODUCTS.productcatid = 77) 
    AND (SS.initialdate BETWEEN @rvPurchaseStart AND @rvPurchaseEnd)
```

From that list, I then need the following query to run for each member in that list:

```
SELECT        
    SITES.sitename, MEMBERS.scancode, MEMBERS.lname, 
    MEMBERS.fname, MEMBERS.mtypeid, MEMBERS.status, 
    PRODUCTS.description, SS.initialdate, 
    SS.initialquantity, SS.usedquantity, SS.dateexpire, 
    EMPLOYEES.lname AS Expr1, EMPLOYEES.fname AS Expr2
FROM             
    SITES 
INNER JOIN
    MEMBERS ON SITES.siteid = MEMBERS.siteid 
INNER JOIN
    SS ON MEMBERS.memid = SS.memid 
INNER JOIN
    PRODUCTCATS 
INNER JOIN
    PRODUCTS ON PRODUCTCATS.productcatid = PRODUCTS.productcatid 
    ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid 
INNER JOIN
    EMPLOYEES ON SS.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
WHERE        
    (PRODUCTS.productcatid <> '68') 
    AND (PRODUCTS.departmentid = '5') 
    AND (MEMBERS.status = 'A') 
    AND (SS.usedquantity < SS.initialquantity) 
    AND (PRODUCTS.scancode <> 'PASSCOMP1' OR
         PRODUCTS.scancode <> 'PASSCOMP3' OR
         PRODUCTS.scancode <> 'PASSCOMP5') 
    AND (PRODUCTS.inactive = 'False')
```

I really appreciate the help!!!

Comment: Please format your question to be readable.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometnihg like this? Just add the fist query as table to your second query.

```
SELECT 
    SITES.sitename, MEMBERS.scancode, 
    MEMBERS.lname, MEMBERS.fname, MEMBERS.mtypeid, 
    MEMBERS.status, PRODUCTS.description, SS.initialdate, 
    SS.initialquantity, SS.usedquantity, SS.dateexpire, 
    EMPLOYEES.lname AS Expr1, EMPLOYEES.fname AS Expr2 
FROM 
    SITES 
INNER JOIN 
    MEMBERS ON SITES.siteid = MEMBERS.siteid 
INNER JOIN 
    SS ON MEMBERS.memid = SS.memid 
INNER JOIN 
    PRODUCTCATS 
INNER JOIN 
    PRODUCTS ON PRODUCTCATS.productcatid = PRODUCTS.productcatid 
       ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid 
INNER JOIN 
    EMPLOYEES ON SS.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         MEMBERS.memid 
     FROM 
         SITES 
     INNER JOIN 
         MEMBERS ON SITES.siteid = MEMBERS.siteid 
     INNER JOIN 
         SS ON MEMBERS.memid = SS.memid 
     INNER JOIN 
         PRODUCTCATS 
     INNER JOIN 
         PRODUCTS ON PRODUCTCATS.productcatid = PRODUCTS.productcatid 
             ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid 
     INNER JOIN 
         EMPLOYEES ON SS.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid 
     WHERE 
         (PRODUCTS.productcatid = 77) 
         AND (SS.initialdate BETWEEN @rvPurchaseStart AND @rvPurchaseEnd)) TMP_TABLE ON MEMBERS.memid = TMP_TABLE.memid 
WHERE 
    (PRODUCTS.productcatid <> '68') 
    AND (PRODUCTS.departmentid = '5') 
    AND (MEMBERS.status = 'A') 
    AND (SS.usedquantity < SS.initialquantity) 
    AND (PRODUCTS.scancode <> 'PASSCOMP1' OR PRODUCTS.scancode <> 'PASSCOMP3' OR PRODUCTS.scancode <> 'PASSCOMP5') 
    AND (PRODUCTS.inactive = 'False')
```

Comment: @marc_s thanks. Was having trouble with formating. Was formating for pas 14 minuties without success

Comment: Highlight those code lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Or just insert each line by at least **4 spaces** - that's really all there is!